# JavaScript image gallery slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slideshow

I'm trying to make a simple photography website with a photo gallery slider navigation, but when I click to see the next image, the browser repositions to the top of the page. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix that issue? Thank you in advance!

html code:

```
<div class="slider_nav">
<a href="#" class="left_arrow"><img src="./assets/images/arrow_left.png" width="50px"></i>
</a>
<ul class="bullets">
<li class="bullet current_bullet">&bull;</li>
<li class="bullet">&bull;</li>
<li class="bullet">&bull;</li>
<li class="bullet">&bull;</li>
</ul>
<a href="#" class="right_arrow"><img src="./assets/images/arrow_right.png" width="50px"></a>
</div>
</div>
```

javascript code:

```
var everything = function () {

$(".right_arrow").click(function () {
var currentSlide = $(".current_slide");
var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();
var currentBullet = $(".current_bullet");
var nextBullet = currentBullet.next();

if (nextSlide.length === 0) {
nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
nextBullet = $(".bullet").first();
}

currentSlide.fadeOut(800).removeClass("current_slide");
nextSlide.fadeIn(800).addClass("current_slide");

currentBullet.removeClass("current_bullet");
nextBullet.addClass("current_bullet");
});


$(".left_arrow").click(function () {
    var currentSlide = $(".current_slide");
    var prevSlide = currentSlide.prev();


var currentBullet = $(".current_bullet");
var prevBullet = currentBullet.prev();

if (prevSlide.length === 0) {
prevSlide = $('.slide').last();
prevBullet = $(".bullet").last();
}

currentSlide.fadeOut(800).removeClass("current_slide");
prevSlide.fadeIn(800).addClass("current_slide");

currentBullet.removeClass("current_bullet");
prevBullet.addClass("current_bullet");
});

};
$(document).ready(everything);
```

Comment: Can you put your code in a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

You must put

```
event.preventDefault()
```

in the handler click on left_arrow and right_arrow.

Read this:
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp